# Ionic app on device, $http not working if not on --livereload

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

So when I do: `ionic run ios --device --livereload` the app will launch in the device an works fine.

But when I do: `ionic run ios --device` , the web service doesn't seem to load.

Is this a CORS issue? I have `cordova-plugin-whitelist` installed and have this in my config.xml

`<allow-navigation href="*"/>`

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on this page? Specifically regarding the `<meta>` tags for `Content-Security-Policy`?